# Creating Messaging APP for mobile phones

Tags: android, message, windows-phone-8.1

I want to create simple messaging app for my class project. example WhatsApp, viber ( I want to keep it very simple). I will be targeting for Android and Windows phone platform. How do I start writing one ? what kind of client server architecture I will need to send messages to cross platform ?

any examples or documents are highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can look at MQTT. It is a protocol for Machine to Machine communications and there are a lot of implementations in different languages. I tried it in a Java to Android communications ad its use is very straightforward. There is also an Eclipse project for it, [Paho project](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/).

Comment: If you think it can help, you can accept the answer